# terraform azurerm_virtual_machine_extension 'settings' json fails to parse when using join operator

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following terraform block to run a custom script on a windows VM

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "install_script" {
  name                 = "install_script"
  virtual_machine_id   = var.myvm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10" 

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive  -command \" echo hi \""
    }
    SETTINGS
}
```

This works as the command is 1 line... but for readability, I am trying to use a join operator to split up the command as such

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "install_script" {
  name                 = "install_script"
  virtual_machine_id   = var.myvm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10" 

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "${(join(" ", (["powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive",
                     "-command \"",
                     "echo hi",
                     "\""])))}"
    }
    SETTINGS
}
```

I keep getting the error in terraform output in pipeline

```
│ Error: "settings" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'e' after object key:value pair
│ 
│   with azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.install_script,
│   on main.tf line 92, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "install_script":
│   92:     settings = <<SETTINGS
│   93:     {
│   94:         "commandToExecute": "${(join(" ", (["powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive",
│   95:                       "-command \"",
│   96:                       "echo hi",
│   97:                       "\""])))}"
│   98:     }
│   99:     SETTINGS
```

To my knowledge, join would reduce the multiple lines down to one string.
And even though I am defining the items over multiple lines, it should not complain since
the join operator is wrapped inside parenthesis (), as well as the list items being wrapped in parenthesis ().

Comment: You can create a local variable with everything you need and then just reference that variable instead of trying to do so much in JSON. Also, instead of using heredoc syntax you can use `jsonencode` built-in function and then you don't have to worry if the corresponding result will be JSON or not.

Answer (score 0):

To properly escape `\`, you need to use `\\\`, which means that you will have:

```
<<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "${(join(" ", (["powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive",
                     "-command \\\"",
                     "echo hi",
                     "\\\""])))}"
    }
SETTINGS
```